# Firebug/Console style hover effect

Tags: css, console, firebug, highlight

Think I know the answer to this one, but just thought there may be some genius out there whos know of a way to do this...

Basically I am making a site editor kind of thing and it would be amazingly handy if I could replicate the way Firebug and the Chrome console highlights elements when you hover over their code in the html/elements tabs of those inspectors...

Its not something I can do with background effects because that does not highlight the whole Div (the contents show above the highlight) and I don't think there is anyway of making a div overlay over the top of all the content but have it not block mouseovers on underlying elements...

Anyone any ideas? Is there any browser specific code that achieves this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

In general, Firefox extensions are mostly JavaScript. Since Firebug is BSD licensed, you can browse its source code on its [project site](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/). Maybe you'll find the relevant code and get an idea how to solve your specific task.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an `outline` in CSS on mouseover - that would highlight the element without changing its position, as `outline` does not effect layout.  A `box-shadow` would also work similarly.

In fact, it looks to me like Firebug adds a dark bluish `box-shadow` to elements to highlight them.